# JQuery toggle div and change button text

Tags: jquery

I have a working script that toggles my div, and it works great but I can't figure out how to also change the button text when clicked. I need the button text to be "Hide Spreads" when the spread div is shown, and "Show Spreads" when the spread div is not shown.

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".spread").show();
  $(".show_hide").show();
  $('.show_hide').click(function(){
    $(".spread").toggle();
  });
});
```

Button:

```
<input type="button" class="show_hide" value="Hide Spreads" />
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `$(this).val()` to get value of the button and check it against the other possible value.

```js
$('.show_hide').click(function(){
    $(".spread").toggle();
    $(this).val( $(this).val() == 'Hide Spreads' ? 'Show Spreads' : 'Hide Spreads' );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" class="show_hide" value="Hide Spreads">
<div class="spread">Test</div>
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I was so close earlier, I was missing the `.val()`. Will accept as answer when allowed.

Answer (score 3):

you can use $(this).text() for get button text and change it by if else.

```
<button id="show_hide">Show</button>
<div id="display"></div>
<script>
$("#show_hide").click(function(){
    $("#display").toggle();
    if($(this).text() == "Show"){
       $(this).text("Hide");
    }else{
       $(this).text("Show");
    }
});
</script>
```